# How to achieve the desired landscape and portrait layout (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, landscape-portrait

I am trying to include resizing functionality to my app by supporting landscape portion as well as portrait. I have no problem achieving the portrait layout which is this one: 
[image]

whoever when I rotate the emulator everything becomes a mess. I am trying to set the frames of all of the components to the desired values when the rotation changes. However, what I get is a big mess and the components are not placed where I want. Any suggestions on how to achieve the portrait and landscape layouts? I want to achieve this landscape layout:
[image]

Here is my code in the view controller:

```
class EditViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var hideKeyboardOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var iconPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var resolutionTitleDeadLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var achievingDateDeadLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var chooseAnIconDeadLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelButtonOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButtonOutlet: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var resolutionTitle: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

let kComponentCount: Int = 1
let kIconComponent: Int = 0
var iconStruct: Icons?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    iconStruct = Icons()
    updateInterface()
}

@IBAction func hideKeyboard(sender: AnyObject) {
    resolutionTitle.resignFirstResponder()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
}

override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    updateInterface()
}


@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    var strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    NSLog("\(datePicker.date)")
    var currentDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
    var pickedIcon: String = iconStruct!.urlImageStrings[iconPicker.selectedRowInComponent(kIconComponent)]

    var newResolution = ["name":resolutionTitle.text,"achievingDate":strDate,"startingDate":"\(currentDate)","icon":"\(pickedIcon)","isAchieved":"N"] as Dictionary<String,String>
    //if the resolution title is not empty...
    if(!resolutionTitle.text.isEmpty){
        //... create new resolution, it and save it to the file.
        var destinationController = (presentingViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! MasterViewController
        destinationController.resolutions.insert(newResolution, atIndex: 0)
        destinationController.notifyTableViewForNewInsertion()
        destinationController.saveDateToFile()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }else{
        // Notify the user that the title text field is empty
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Flower Selection", message: "Cannot create a resolution with empty title!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
@IBAction func cancelButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return kComponentCount
}


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return iconStruct!.length!
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent   component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView {
    let chosenImage: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: iconStruct?.getImageAtIndex(index: row))
    let workaroundImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: chosenImage.frame)
    workaroundImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: chosenImage.image!)
    return workaroundImageView
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 95
}


func updateInterface(){
    if interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown{
        self.hideKeyboardOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 54, 375, 667)
        self.resolutionTitleDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 39, 174, 21)
        self.resolutionTitle.frame = CGRectMake(43, 68, 289, 30)
        self.achievingDateDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(101, 106, 174, 21)
        self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(27, 135, 320, 162)
        self.chooseAnIconDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(101, 315, 181, 21)
        self.iconPicker.frame = CGRectMake(57,344,262,150)
        self.cancelButtonOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(86, 516, 62, 45)
        self.saveButtonOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(213, 516, 62, 45)
        NSLog("Portret")
    }else{
        self.hideKeyboardOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(0,38, 667,339)
        self.resolutionTitleDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100,39,446,21)
        self.resolutionTitle.frame = CGRectMake(43,68,581,30)
        self.achievingDateDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(115,106,144,21)
        self.datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(43,135,255,162)
        self.chooseAnIconDeadLabel.frame = CGRectMake(391,106,181,21)
        self.iconPicker.frame = CGRectMake(352,135,258,187)
        self.cancelButtonOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(147,322,62,45)
        self.saveButtonOutlet.frame = CGRectMake(450,322,62,45)
        NSLog("Landscape")
    }

}


}
```

Comment: I think you should read some tutorial about size classes (example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) and about auto layout. This is really bad practise to do all that thing in code by changing frames.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the website that you suggested. The thing is, I recently switched to ios, I used to develop for android and that process is WAaayy easier on android. It is unbelievably confusing in ios.

Comment: You can configure UI elements in storyboard for every iOS device for both orientation without code at all.

Comment: Are you developing just for iOS9? (Hint: develop just for iOS9)

Comment: Never use hard coded frames. Use auto layout and size classes for this. It's a bit frustrating to understand at first, but when you do it's *so* much easier (and better). I can recommend this book: http://makeapppie.com/2015/06/25/practical-auto-layout-are-you-ready-for-ios-9/

Comment: Thank you guys for your recommendations and suggestions, really! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (by a country mile) to do this is to use `UIStackView` (or rather nested `UIStackViews`).

You will have several "components" of your view where each component is a collection of views inside a `UIStackView`.

1. The titleStackView
2. The dateStackView
3. The iconStackView
4. The buttonStackView

### The setup

Each of these should be a `UIStackView`.

The `titleStackView` will be vertical because the `UILabel` is above the `UITextField` same for the others except the `buttonStackView` will be horizontal. (There is an axis property on `UIStackView`).

Next you need another `UIStackView`. This will contain the `dateComponent` and the `iconStackView`. I'll call this stack view the `mainStackView`.

Finally you need another stack view (`outerStackView`) that is vertical and contains the `titleStackView` the `mainStackView` and the `buttonStackView`.

### The switch

Now, when the orientation changes between landscape and portrait all you have to do is update the `axis` property on the `mainStackView`. If the orientation is portrait set...

```
mainStackView.axis = .vertical
```

and if the orientation is landscape set...

```
mainStackView.axis = .horizontal
```

All you need is three lines of code to actually make the change and not a single `UILayoutConstraint` in sight! (Well, 4 to pin the `outerStackView` to the edges of the screen but that's it).

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev no worries. Let me know if you get stuck. When creating the stack views start at the components first. Work inside out. It makes everything easier.

Comment: Will do, mate. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev also. When stacking views in interface builder. Remove all layout constraints first and then select the views you want to stalk together (title label and text field) and then hit the "Stack" button in the bottom right corner.

Comment: I was just checking where is this UIStackView (I thought it is a separate UI component) Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using xCode 6.4 and just found out that the "Stack" button is not supported :/ The reason I am using this version of Xcode is because it is required by the course I am studying in uni. I am going to accept this answer because you were very helpful and dedicated some of your time to help me and I appreciate that! I will try to ask my lecturer if I am going to be fine if using newer version of XCode. Thanks again!

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev anything that can be done in Xcode 6.4 can also be done in Xcode 7. It seems odd to be told you have to use a version of Xcode that's almost a year out of date though. Let me know if you can't update and I'll see if I can provide an answer. But it's a hell of a lot more difficult without using UIStackView.

Comment: Well, not difficult but complicated.

Comment: Yes, will do mate. I will try to explain to my lecturer. Thanks again and have a lovely day :)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev thanks. Just a thought. You can install the Xcode 7 beta version alongside the Xcode 6.4 version so you can have both of them to try it out. I'd recommend duplicating your project before opening in Xcode 7 though so that it doesn't make any changes to the Xcode 6.4 one. Just copy the folder to somewhere else to make a copy of it.

Comment: Yes, will definitely try that. I was not sure if you can have two separate versions of Xcode. I am curious to see if it is that easy in XCode 7.